# How do I inject/create an object at runtime based on some processing using Ninject?

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

How do I inject and create an object at runtime based on some processing?

In the code below, the main calculator (`GridCalculator`) (snipped for brevity) has a dependency on a `PricesCalculator`. However, some processing need to happen in the main calculator first prior to the instantiation of a PricesCalculator. The `GridPortfolios` property of the `PricesCalculator` will always and can only be know at runtime. I am not sure how to set the value of this property at runtime (I am not concerned about the other two constructor arguments `valDatePrices` & `edDatePrices`).

I would like to use Ninject to handle the creation of this object since there are dependencies which have been wired up correctly.

My Ninject setup is as follows:

`Load` Method of my Ninject Module

```
public override void Load()
    {

        Bind<IFileReader<IList<Prices>>>().To<PricesReader>().Named("ValDatePrices");
        Bind<IFileReader<IList<Prices>>>().To<PricesReader>().Named("EDDatePrices");
        Bind<IFileReader<IEnumerable<GridRow>>>().ToMethod(GridReader);    
        /* other declarations*/
        Bind<ICalculator<PriceSet>>().To<PricesCalculator>(); // this is probably not correct
        Bind<ICalculator<IList<GridExposure>>>().To<GridCalculator>();

    }
```

**EDGridCalculator**

```
public class GridCalculator : ICalculator<IList<GridExposure>>
{
    public ICalculator<PriceSet> PricesCalculator { get; set; }

    // not sure if constructor injection is the way to go
    public GridCalculator(
                      ICalculator<PriceSet> pricesCalculator
                    , IFileReader<IEnumerable<GridRow>> gridReader)
    {


        this.PricesCalculator = pricesCalculator;
        this.GridReader = gridReader;
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        var gdResults = GridReader().Read();
        var pivot = new Pivot(gdResults);
        IList<string> keys = pivot.Keys();

        // Need my PricesCalculator object to be constructed 
        // with the "keys" variable and the other dependencies noted in Load()

        // Continue to use "pivot" at later stages of processing.

    }
}
```

**PriceCalculator**

```
public class PriceCalculator: ICalculator<PriceSet>{
    [Inject] public IList<string> GridPortfolios;

    PriceSet _priceSet;

    public PricesCalculator(
            [Named("ValDatePrices")]IFileReader<IList<Prices>> valDatePrices
          , [Named("EDDatePrices")]IFileReader<IList<Prices>> edDatePrices
          /* we could do constructor injection */
          )
    {
        this.ValDatePricesReader = valDatePrices;
        this.EDDatePricesReader = edDatePrices;
        _priceSet = new PriceSet();
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {    // calcs happen here
          Result = new PriceSet(); 
    }  

}
```

Comment: Have you considered method injection?

Comment: My answer below assumes you can change the interface of the prices calculator. If this is not the case I can give you another solution

Answer (score 0):

Hy
This is only a matter of designing the right interfaces and has nothing to do with ninject. In this case you shouldnt use constructor injection for your keys data. Simply change the calculate method of the prices calculator to take in a parameter. The the calculator be constructor injected but when calling calculate on the prices calculator pass in the necessary data.

Daniel